# Error non numeric argument to a binary operator

Tags: r, plot, polynomials

I want to plot an error graph for a set of polynomials. My command line is as follows:

```
W=function(x){(x^2 - 4*x + 3)*exp(1)^((x*log(x))/2)}
Z=function(x){7*x^3 - 40*x^2 + 69*x -36}
plot(abs(W-Z))
```

and then I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a function, it has to be evaluated at a set of points. Simply doing `W-Z` is trying to subtract one function object from another, which doesn't make sense, hence the error. You can simply define a sequence over which to evaluate the functions and plot the absolute difference. For example,

```
x <- seq(1, 100, 0.1)

plot(abs(W(x) - Z(x)))
```

Note that since you're supplying only a single argument to `plot()`, the default x-axis label will be `Index`. To change it, you can use the `xlab=` argument like so:

```
plot(abs(W(x) - Z(x)), xlab="x")
```

Now the x-axis label will be "x". For more information on plotting options, check out the documentation for `plot` using `?plot`.

Comment: Hi Alex I tried using your advice and it works, if you wouldn't mind just helping me out with one more thing. The x axis in the plot says 'index'. What does it mean?

Comment: @JemuelChandrakumaran: "Index" is the default x-axis label when you supply only a single argument to the `plot()` function. You can change it to anything you want using the `xlab=` argument in `plot()`.